# How do I change the colour of an element within a div on rollover using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that has a div within it.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I would like to change the colour of the ".child" element on hover using javascript. I have to use javascript and not jquery and not css.

Any ideas?

Comment: why can't you use CSS for this? with css you can just use the `:hover` on the child div..

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't. Its a stupid long story. It would be so easy if i could. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an eventListener to all of the children, listening forthe event *mouseover*.

```js
var children = document.getElementsByClassName("child");
for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
  children[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
    this.style.background = "grey"; 
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the children to go back to white when the mouse leaves use the mouseout event with a new eventListener.

```
children[i].addEventListener("mouseout",function() {
   this.style.background = "white"; 
})
```

Comment: Or with CSS: `.child:hover{ background: grey; }`.. Don't see the point of doing this with javascript..

Comment: I know...but they asked for it in JavaScript...would be so much easier with CSS.